# How to get an image of what System.Drawing.Graphics object draws?

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

See the following method:

```
void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics g)
{
//How can I start record what 'g' will draw to an image object?
g.DrawLine(0,0,50,50);
g.DrawImage(...);
..
..
etc.

}
```

Now how can I get An Image about what 'g' drew?
Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have to be more specific i.e do you want to view the image on the screen? Do you want to save the image to file?

Comment: assume I have a Graphics object 'g' and I drew lines,rectangles,..etc,
If I want to get a ready Image about what drawn no to redraw the lines,rectangles..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try...

```
using (Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(inImage)) 
{ 
  g.Clear(Color.White); 
  g.DrawLine(0,0,50,50); 
}
```

This will then draw the line on to the image. Just make sure the image is big enough...

Also you can draw straight on to a form by overriding the OnPaint event and getting the graphics object from the eventArgs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one

```
Bitmap bmp;
...
{
 InitializeComponent();
 bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width,this.Height,Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle));
}

void Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
  g.DrawLine(0,0,50,50);
  ..
  .. 
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,0,0);
}
```